# Let $D^*$ be the parallelogram bounded by the lines $y=3x+4$, $y=3x$, $y=\frac{1}{2}(x+4)$, $y=\frac{x}{2}$. Let $D=[0, 1]^2$.

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Let $D^*$ be the parallelogram bounded by the lines $y=3x+4$, $y=3x$, $y=\frac{1}{2}(x+4)$, $y=\frac{x}{2}$. Let $D=[0, 1]^2$. Find an application $T$ such that $T(D*)=D$, $T(0, 0)=(0, 0)$ and preserve the adjacencies of the vertices in a clockwise direction.

I have something, but I don't understand the part that says: "preserve the adjacencies of the vertices in a clockwise direction".

[image]

Is it ok?

[image]

I must determine where the points $A, B, C, D$ are going to give in the region $D$. That is done with the given information, but I don't understand it anymore...

Comment: You need four lines to serve as boundaries for a quadrilateral, but your definition of $D^*$ only gives three.

Comment: @ConnorHarris Right, I forgot to write it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Preserving the adjacencies" probably means that the transformation $T$ does not contain a reflection, so that the vertices $A, B, C, D$ in your picture under the mapping will remain in clockwise order.

To do this, there are many ways to construct such a transformation matrix.  A purely algebraic approach is to observe that since $T(0,0) = (0,0)$, the mapping preserves point $D$, thus it must have the form
$$T(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}px + qy \\ rx + sy \end{bmatrix}$$ for suitable constants $p, q, r, s$.  Then all that is left is to choose particular values of $(x,y)$ and their corresponding desired images under $T$.  To do this you would solve for the nontrivial intersection points; e.g., $C = (4/5, 12/5)$, and we require this point to map to $(1,0)$.  Thus
$$T(4/5, 12/5) = (4(p+3q)/5, 4(r+3s)/5) = (1,0),$$ giving a system of two equations in four unknowns.  Repeating this process with point $A$, which must map to $(0,1)$, gives another two equations in four unknowns.  Solve these and you get the desired transformation matrix.